# Reading mule variables from property file in Mule 4

Tags: dataweave, mule4

I have a scenario where there is a variable defined in my mule flow. In the properties file, there is a property which is a String including the variable defined in the flow. When reading the property from property file, rather than replacing the variable by its value, it is printing it as a text. Mule runtime version is 4.2.2. This works as expected in Mule 3.x but facing issue in 4.x version.

```
<flow name="sample-testFlow1" doc:id="4138e351-316b-40af-a694-c416b5dc317f" >
<http:listener doc:name="Listener" doc:id="424c82c0-3e23-4f61-8e9b-62ec69711493" config-ref="HTTP_Listener_config" path="/test2"/>
<set-variable value='#["EmployeeCode"]' doc:name="Set Variable" doc:id="45bd2007-907b-4749-af14-001ad2cf82a6" variableName="testVariable"/>
<ee:transform doc:name="Transform Message" doc:id="e23dff81-a4e7-4d26-8f9e-b533442ddd5b" >
    <ee:message >
        <ee:set-payload ><![CDATA[%dw 2.0 output application/java --- p('test.prop')]]>/ee:set-payload>
        </ee:message>
    </ee:transform>
</flow>
```

Property File:

```
test.prop=Hello!Variable is #[vars.testVariable]
```

Expected Output: `Hello!Variable is EmployeeCode`

But getting as : `Hello!Variable is #[vars.testVariable]`

Any help is much appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can take a look at the Parse Template Reference in Mule. I believe it'll make your solution much easier. Here's the link to the documentation page->https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-runtime/4.3/parse-template-reference

Please let me know what you think.

Comment: Your suggestion worked exactly the way I wanted it to work. Thank you for your answer.

Answer (score 1):

Just to Add the answer to Aled,

You can read the values from Property/YAML file in Mule `4.x` like below as well.

```
Mule::p('http.port')
```

you can not use `#[...]` to evaluate an expression inside another expression as above said but you can `$()` inside the string in DataWeave to evaluate the DataWeave expression.

Answer (score 0):

That is to be expected. The property is read as a string, not evaluated as an expression. Even if it would be expanded, the result would be an error, because you can not use `#[...]` to evaluate an expression inside another expression, because the contents of the `<ee:set-payload>` element is already a DataWeave expression.

I think that instead of Transform you should try to use the [Dynamic Expression Component](https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-runtime/4.3/dynamic-evaluate-component-reference), to evaluate the expression dynamically. Make the value of the property an expression, without using `#[...]`, ie `"Hello!Variable is " ++ vars.testVariable`.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Alad and Manish for your replies.

I even tried without expression tag '#[]' as suggested, but that is printing as a sting and not the value.

"Hello!Variable is " ++ vars.testVariable evaluated as 'Hello!Variable is vars.testVariable' and not 'Hello!Variable is EmployeeCode'.

Using Mule::p('http.port') returned #["Hello!Variable is" ++ vars.sampleVar]. So, I tried to set this in another variable and read it, but no luck.

Thanks.